# How to detect a Debian package that is no longer needed after an upgrade of its previously dependent package?

Tags: debian, apt, package-management, dependencies, aptitude

Let's say, there is a Debian package named `Foo`, whose version `1.1.1` depends on a package named `Bar`.

Imagine that there is a newer version of `Foo==1.1.2`, which doesn't depend on `Bar` anymore.

After an upgrade the package `Bar` is not automatically uninstalled. Moreover, `apt autoremove` doesn't uninstall this package either.

How do I automatically detect such packages as `Bar` during upgrades of those packages that depend on them? And how do I get rid of such packages as `Bar`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your package `Bar` has probably ended in the state `manual` rather than `auto` as can be confirmed if found in the output of the command:

```
apt-mark showmanual
```

and is thus no longer handled by `apt-get autoremove`.

You can use the tool [`deborphan`](https://manpages.debian.org/deborphan/deborphan) from the package [`deborphan`](https://packages.debian.org/stable/deborphan) specialized to find such packages. It doesn't use the package's `manual` status for its heuristics.

> program that can find unused packages, e.g. libraries
>
> deborphan finds "orphaned" packages on your system. It determines
>   which packages have no other packages depending on their installation
>   and shows you a list of these packages. It is most useful when finding
>   libraries, but it can be used on packages in all sections.

Be warned that it can also give false positives, especially for plugin libraries (libraries that can be removed without causing a dependency issue but their removal will remove a feature somewhere).

You can use the results given by `deborphan` to remove the packages yourself, or mark them back as `auto` with

```
apt-mark auto package1 package2 ...
```

for further handling by `apt-get autoremove`.

Comment: I understand that this isn't a direct answer to the question, but I believe a package's installation script should not itself handle packages removal. Maybe there are advanced solutions with triggers etc, but I wouldn't trust that

Comment: Agreed; in fact package installation scripts *can’t* remove other packages. (And I think this is fine as a direct answer to the stated question.)

Answer (score -1):

I believe that [`apt remove` is Debian's equivalent to Arch's `pacman -Qdtq`](https://askubuntu.com/a/955315/1016650), which simply queries the packages which are no longer required as dependencies.  To remove them, I suspect you'd have to run something like

```
apt remove $(apt autoremove)
```

(as for Arch you'd have to run something like `pacman -R $(pacman -Qdtq)`).

As for automatically removing these packages, I'm not sure about changing the configurations of `apt`, but you could add the above line to your `.bashrc`.

Disclaimer: I haven't done this on Debian, but I have used Arch to do what you want to do.

Comment: No, `apt autoremove` takes care of the removal too.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that.  The link I have in my answer seemed to suggest otherwise.

Comment: The link you give says that `apt autoremove` is equivalent to `pacman -Qdtq | pacman -Rs -`, in its entirety, *i.e.* listing the packages *and* removing them.

Comment: Ah, you're absolutely right.  I misread; sorry about that.